# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent c# pdf inline

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, pdf

So I have been having this problem for a while now for trying to return a pdf inline response. I searched all through the help coding pages for answers to this and can not find something that works yet. I made a simplified example of what I am doing below. But the core is all the same as real production. This issue doesn't always happen, but its annoying when it does. It's almost like it's some weird timing issue or something else I am not seeing is going on.

I get this error System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File Not Found ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

Does anyone know how to fix this??

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PDF(string id, bool inline = false)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream PDFStream = GetPdfStream(id);

            PDFStream.Position = 0;

            string PDFFile = "Test.pdf";


            if (inline)
            {
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", PDFFile));
                Response.BufferOutput = true;
                return File(PDFStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
            }
            else
                return File(PDFStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, PDFFile);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "File Not Found", Ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you're going to create invalid content disposition values in case your filename contains whitespace, certain delimiters, or non-ASCII characters. See RFC 6266 for details.

Answer (score 2):

You must clear  the header first before adding new ones

```
if (inline)
{
   Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", PDFFile));
Response.BufferOutput = true;
return File(PDFStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
else
return File(PDFStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, PDFFile);
```

Comment: I think I tried that. But I will try it again and see how it works out. I am still open for other suggestions in the mean time though.

Comment: Are you sure I shouldn't call Response.Clear() instead of Response.ClearHeaders()?

Comment: @kyleb Response.Clear() as per MSDN erases any buffered HTML output. However, the Clear method erases only the response body; it does not erase response headers. And your requirement is to ClearHeaders

Comment: Now i get Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent :(

Comment: @kyleb this error might because before Response.ClearHeaders soemthing is getting already set my suspect is  MemoryStream PDFStream = GetPdfStream(id);

Comment: Why would me getting a memory stream that is seperate from the headers have anything to do with this error?

Comment: @kyleb because you new error message reports that HTTP headers are already been sent so my guess was the something might be in the method  GetPdfStream. But your right if this new error is reporting after this line Response.BufferOutput = true; then it does not makes sense at all

Comment: Yea GetPdf stream doesn't do anything with http response